# java JTable sort objects

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I am sorry for asking this. But I am having huge problems understanding how to do so.

I have a `JTable`. For that `JTable` I have my own `AbstractTableModel` that returns a custom object for `getValueAt`. Additionally I also have my own `TableCellRenderer` that uses a lot of colors, and uses column value to extract specified values from object that is given by `getValueAt`.

However I would like to be able to sort values. So how would I go about sorting? I would like to be able to receive the two objects, and the column, and sort based on that.

I tried reading bunch of tutorials but they show how to sort either based on string, or just sort without knowing the column.

Also should I be doing sorting in the class where I create the `JTable`, or in `AbstractTableModel` or in `TableCellRenderer`?

Any help or pointing to good tutorial will be greatly appreciated. I am sorry but I really suck at this worsting and have never done it.

Comment: Did you read about  `RowSorter`?